# Always add class="img-responvise" to images inserted into TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE 4.7.9, and when I insert an image via the TinyMCE popup, it inserts the HTML for `<img src="myimage" />` etc. ok, and I know I can add a class using the appearance section of the image popup, but is there a way to make `class="img-responsive"` (or always have a `style="width:100%; height:auto;"` for every image that is inserted)

I have looked on various places but cant seem to work out if it is possible.

I have tried the suggested entry below but didnt work.  I am using a custom plugin.js file for my project - but the JS in the plugin.js for custom image I dont really understand - what I would like to do, is in the Advanced tab always default its value in the Style box to width:100%; height:auto;

Here is the JS can anyone who knows tiny mce tell me how to do it at all -  i see there is a section of code called e . settings . image_advtab but i cant work out how to do it in there - anyone help?

```
 tinymce.PluginManager.add("image", function(e) {
function openmanager() {
    var win, data, dom = e.dom,
        imgElm = e.selection.getNode();
    var width, height, imageListCtrl;
    win = e.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Image Manager',
        data: data,
        classes: 'tinyfilemanager.net',
        file: tfm_path + '/dialog.aspx?type=1&editor=' + e.id + '&lang=' + tinymce.settings.language,
        filetype: 'image',
        width: 900,
        height: 600,
        inline: 1

        //,
        //buttons: [{
        //    text: 'Close',
        //    id: 'btnclosefilemanager',
        //    onclick: 'close',
        //    classes: 'mcebuttonleft mcebtncancel'
        //}]


    })
}

function t() {
    function t() {
        var t = [{
            text: "None",
            value: ""
        }];
        return tinymce.each(e.settings.image_list, function(e) {
            t.push({
                text: e.text || e.title,
                value: e.value || e.url,
                menu: e.menu
            })
        }), t
    }

    function n(e) {
        var t, n, r, i;
        t = a.find("#width")[0], n = a.find("#height")[0], r = t.value(), i = n.value(), a.find("#constrain")[0].checked() && l && c && r && i && (e.control == t ? (i = Math.round(r / l * i), n.value(i)) : (r = Math.round(i / c * r), t.value(r))), l = r, c = i
    }

    function r() {
        function t(t) {
            t.onload = t.onerror = function() {
                t.onload = t.onerror = null, e.selection.select(t), e.nodeChanged()
            }
        }
        var n = a.toJSON();
        "" === n.width && (n.width = null), "" === n.height && (n.height = null), "" === n.style && (n.style = null), n = {
            src: n.src,
            alt: n.alt,
            width: n.width,
            height: n.height,
            style: n.style
        }, f ? d.setAttribs(f, n) : (n.id = "__mcenew", e.insertContent(d.createHTML("img", n)), f = d.get("__mcenew"), d.setAttrib(f, "id", null)), t(f)
    }

    function i(e) {
        return e && (e = e.replace(/px$/, "")), e
    }

    function o() {
        function e(e) {
            return e.length > 0 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(e) && (e += "px"), e
        }
        var t = a.toJSON(),
            n = d.parseStyle(t.style);
        delete n.margin, n["margin-top"] = n["margin-bottom"] = e(t.vspace), n["margin-left"] = n["margin-right"] = e(t.hspace), n["border-width"] = e(t.border), a.find("#style").value(d.serializeStyle(d.parseStyle(d.serializeStyle(n))))
    }
    var a, s, l, c, u, d = e.dom,
        f = e.selection.getNode();
    l = d.getAttrib(f, "width"), c = d.getAttrib(f, "height"), "IMG" != f.nodeName || f.getAttribute("data-mce-object") ? f = null : s = {
        src: d.getAttrib(f, "src"),
        alt: d.getAttrib(f, "alt"),
        width: l,
        height: c
    }, e.settings.image_list && (u = {
        name: "target",
        type: "listbox",
        label: "Image list",
        values: t(),
        onselect: function(e) {
            var t = a.find("#alt");
            (!t.value() || e.lastControl && t.value() == e.lastControl.text()) && t.value(e.control.text()), a.find("#src").value(e.control.value())
        }
    });
    var p = [{
        type: 'container',
        layout: 'flex',
        classes: 'combobox has-open',
        label: 'Source',
        direction: 'row',
        items: [{
            name: 'src',
            type: 'textbox',
            filetype: 'image',
            size: 35,
            classes: 'img_' + e.id,
            autofocus: true
        }, {
            name: 'upl_img',
            type: 'button',
            classes: 'btn open',
            icon: 'browse',
            onclick: openmanager,
            tooltip: 'Upload image'
        }]
    }, u, {
        name: "alt",
        type: "textbox",
        label: "Image description"
    }, {
        type: "container",
        label: "Dimensions",
        layout: "flex",
        direction: "row",
        align: "center",
        spacing: 5,
        items: [{
            name: "width",
            type: "textbox",
            maxLength: 3,
            size: 3,
            onchange: n
        }, {
            type: "label",
            text: "x"
        }, {
            name: "height",
            type: "textbox",
            maxLength: 3,
            size: 3,
            onchange: n
        }, {
            name: "constrain",
            type: "checkbox",
            checked: !0,
            text: "Constrain proportions"
        }]
    }];
    e.settings.image_advtab ? (f && (s.hspace = i(f.style.marginLeft || f.style.marginRight), s.vspace = i(f.style.marginTop || f.style.marginBottom), s.border = i(f.style.borderWidth), s.style = e.dom.serializeStyle(e.dom.parseStyle(e.dom.getAttrib(f, "style")))), a = e.windowManager.open({
        title: "Edit image",
        data: s,
        bodyType: "tabpanel",
        body: [{
            title: "General",
            type: "form",
            items: p
        }, {
            title: "Advanced",
            type: "form",
            pack: "start",
            items: [{
                label: "Style",
                name: "style",
                type: "textbox"
            }, {
                type: "form",
                layout: "grid",
                packV: "start",
                columns: 2,
                padding: 0,
                alignH: ["left", "right"],
                defaults: {
                    type: "textbox",
                    maxWidth: 50,
                    onchange: o
                },
                items: [{
                    label: "Vertical space",
                    name: "vspace"
                }, {
                    label: "Horizontal space",
                    name: "hspace"
                }, {
                    label: "Border",
                    name: "border"
                }]
            }]
        }],
        onSubmit: r
    })) : a = e.windowManager.open({
        title: "Edit image",
        data: s,
        body: p,
        onSubmit: r
    })
}
e.addButton("image", {
    icon: "image",
    tooltip: "Insert/edit image",
    onclick: t,
    stateSelector: "img:not([data-mce-object])"
}), e.addMenuItem("image", {
    icon: "image",
    text: "Insert image",
    onclick: t,
    context: "insert",
    prependToContext: !0
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your TinyMCE initializator:

```
image_class_list: [
    {title: 'img-responsive', value: 'img-responsive'},
]
```

Check docs here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_class_list